# Laravel Eloquent data ranking

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to range users, based on how many rows there are in the DB with ther id.
My dataset look like this (simplified):

```
A .... John
A .... John
B .... Mike
A .... John
B .... Mike
C .... Denis
```

I want first three unique names, ordered by how many times a value on the left appears.
**Can I do that with Laravel's eloquent ORM?**

A result would then be:

```
John
Mike
Denis
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want specifically a laravel solution? Or a "pure sql" solution can work for you?

Comment: Well, both would do.. :) I was just curious about Eloquent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how you do it with Laravel's Eloquent ORM

```
Model::select('name')
->groupBy('name')
->orderBy(DB::raw('count(name)'), 'desc')
->take(3)
->get();
```

If you are using Laravel 3 then use snake case:

```
Model::select('name')->group_by('name')->order_by(DB::raw('count(name)'), 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

If you wish you may just use Query Builder (Fluent) by using `DB::table('tableName')->` instead of `Model::`.

**Notes**:

- `DB::raw()` instructs Laravel not to put
  backtics there.
- `take()` limits the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not a laravel solution, but it might work (pure SQL, specifically MySQL):

```
select name
from yourTable
where ... # Your filter conditions go here
group by name
order by count(id) desc
limit 3;
```

Hope this helps